# passing props from <Router> to children

Tags: react-router

My `LanguageProvider` component adds `messages` property to its children. I was able to pass this parameter down to route components with the following code:

```
function createElement(Component, props) {
  // TODO accessing this.propName seems to be an undocumented feature
  return <Component {...props} messages={this.messages} />;
}

render(
  <LanguageProvider>
    <Router history={history} createElement={createElement}>
      <Route path="/" component={App}/>
    </Router>
  </LanguageProvider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

I haven't found accesing `this.propertyName` to be mentioned in the documentation and I've found this feature only by the trial-and-error approach. Also I don't know how to pass all the extra props from `Router` to route components like `{...this.props}`.

For completeness this is `render` method of `LanguageProvider`:

```
render() {
  return React.cloneElement(this.props.children, {...this.props, messages: {foo: 'bar'} });
}
```

Any ideas how to do it standard way?

Comment: Have you looked at [react-i18n](https://github.com/i18next/react-i18next)? They too provide a language provider, but ask each component to be wrapped in `translate` HOC to gain access to translation methods. Perhaps you could follow a similar approach, rather than passing props through the router?

Comment: I was using react-intl until found and reported the issue https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/issues/311. But my question should not focus on i18n. I am asking generally for all similar usecases.

Comment: I was more suggesting the use of HOC as a way of accessing context, rather than relying on react router passing props directly. But no worries.